# maven project and glassfish provided dependencies

Tags: jakarta-ee, intellij-idea, maven-3, glassfish-5

I have a J2ee project that uses technologies such as Jsf, EJB, Persistence API etc.
Most of these dependencies are provided with glassfish 5 into the modules directory. But how am I suppose to know which versions I need for these modules. for example:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ejb</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ejb-api</artifactId>
            <version>LATEST</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

for now I look up in the maven central repository for this information:  GroupId, ArtifactID, Latest Version. But there is a simpler way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When working with Java EE and application servers, your `pom.xml` should contain only this dependency [java-ee-8.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax/javaee-api/8.0) (for glassfish 5)

Comment: thank you, but it doesn't seem to work for me. It work at compilation but for example a jsf page is not even parsed. I still have the <h:component

Comment: I'm sorry I've found my mistake. The structure of my project was wrong, and the java folder was into the webapp directory. Now everything (almost) is ok. It is very convenient to add all these dependencies with just 6  lines !